# Impala: count(distinct) with multiple where statement criteria?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a health outcome database where I'd like to be able to query counts of subjects that meet a specific diagnosis string within a certain date range. Dummy data (`my_table`) would look like this (`Date` as a timestamp):

```
subjid   Diagnosis  Date
----------------------------------------
Subj001  Z12345     2019-02-05 00:00:00
Subj001  Z12345     2017-01-10 00:00:00
Subj002  Z12345     2018-08-14 00:00:00
Subj002  Z12345     2014-03-20 00:00:00
Subj002  Z12345     2013-07-23 00:00:00
Subj003  Y56789     2016-08-16 00:00:00
```

There can be multiple entries for each subject in subjid, each with a corresponding Diagnosis code. So far my query looks like:

```
select 
    subjid, Diagnosis, Date,
    count(subjid) over (partition by Diagnosis) as count 
from 
    my_table
where 
    Diagnosis in ('Z12345') 
    and diag_date >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

However, the issue is that I can't include a distinct statement within the parens for count, as this returns an error. What I'm looking for is the count of unique subjects that satisfy the Diagnosis code string after a particular date; I'm *not* interested in how many times the Diagnosis code string occurs for each patient.

**Question:** is there a way to count the total number of unique occurrences of each given subject that match a particular diagnosis string after a particular date?

Solution needs to be in Impala. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you provide the expected result of your question. For instance, what do you expect to see from the data you provided if the query successfully worked?

Comment: Many thanks @PeonProgrammer. In essence, I'd like the query to return a total count (scalar) of all unique subjects that match a given diagnosis code string, after a particular date. Optimally a distinct statement in the parens after count would achieve this - but doing so returns an error. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't the count be 1 for all of these then if you want unique occurrences by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is the sum of `dense_rank()`s:

```
select subjid, Diagnosis, Date,
       (dense_rank() over (partition by diagnosis order by subjid asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by diagnosis order by subjid desc)
       ) as num_subjids
from my_table
where Diagnosis in ('Z12345') and
      diag_date >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Many thanks for suggestion @GordonLinoff; shall give that a whirl and get back to you.